# Simple way to get keys/mouse buttons working in Synergy (mac client, pc server)

Tags: keyboard, synergy, key-binding, mouse-buttons

I'm trying to get Synergy working running as client on my Mac with SynergyKM Preferences panel. It's performing generally fine (just some real slow downs when my network is under heavy use, usually from youtube videos).

The main thing I want to get working is none of the special buttons on my mouse are working on the client.. just the scroll and middle click.. but I have back/forward buttons I'd like to have working.

Also my Windows Comfort Curve Keyboard has some extra keys and I'd like to know how to set those up to perform operations on my Mac client.

I could have sworn that home/end weren't working but they seem to be now.. perhaps it's application specific..

Answer (score 0):

Home and End keys are handled on a per application basis in OSX .

As for your specific mappings, I think you have to manage that on your synergy server end in the config file over there. I think you can may be able to use a debug window server side to see what signals it gets for your non-standard inputs.